# MailChimp API PUT update list member

Tags: mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

Starting January 16, 2024 this endpoint seems to have broke.

### Add or update a list member.

> https://mailchimp.com/developer/marketing/api/list-members/add-or-update-list-member/.
>
> PUT /lists/{list_id}/members/{subscriber_hash}

I can still add new members from this endpoint, but updating returns this error:

```
{
    "title": "Member Exists",
    "status": 400,
    "detail": "***@******.com is already a list member. Use PUT to insert or update list members.",
    "instance": "a808bd33-ddcf-5658-3e4a-601fe33616b7"
}
```

I've contact support, but they are useless and just send me docs for the API.  Any hack or trick to get this to work again?

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be an issue with a single email address.  I removed that email address, re-subscribed it and now the endpoint works as expected.